# chart.js data does not show up on initial page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have a chart in react using chart.js here is the code

```
function Bar() {

const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState([{}])

useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/get').then((response) =>{
          console.log(response.data)
          setBackendData(response.data)
        })
      }, [])
//const total = backendData[1].total;
//console.log(total)
// const NethEmpty = 30-total


//monday chart data
var nethkinData = {
    labels: backendData.map(time => time.time),
    datasets: [{
        data: backendData.map(total => 30 - (total.total)),
        label: "Empty parking spaces",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(211,211,211,0.5)",
        borderColor: "rgb(211,211,211)"
    }]
}
// nethkin chart options
var nethkinOptions = {
        scales: {
            y: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                suggestedMax: 30,
                ticks: {
                    color: 'Grey',
                },
                grid: {
                    display: true,
                }
            },
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    color: 'Grey',
                }
            },
        },
        animation: {
            y: {
              duration: 3000,
              from: 3000
            }
        },
        
}



useEffect(() => {
    // var test = document.getElementById("0").getContext('2d');
    // test.destroy();
    // monday chart
    
    var ctx = document.getElementById('nethkinChart').getContext('2d');
    let nethkinChartStatus = Chart.getChart("nethkinChart");
    if (nethkinChartStatus != undefined) {
        nethkinChartStatus.destroy();
    }
    var nethkinChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: nethkinData,
        options: nethkinOptions,
        
    });
}, [])

return (
    <>
        {/* browser tab title and icon */}
        <Head>
            <link rel="icon" href="/latech.ico"/>
            <title>Parking Statistics</title>
        </Head>
        
        <Sidebar pageWrapId={'page-wrap'} outerContainerId={'outer-container'}/>


        {/* navbar title */}
        <div className={lots.navbar}>
            <h2>Parking Statistics</h2>
        </div>


        {/* page content */}
        {/* bar charts */}
        {/* monday */}
        <div className={stats.chart}>
            <h2>Nethkin Stats</h2>
            <canvas id='nethkinChart'></canvas>
        </div>
    </>
)
    }



    export default Bar;
```

The problem I a having is that when I first load the page the data will not be there.
Also when I reload the page the data will not show up the data only shows up when I change the chart from line to bar then the data will be there until I leave the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your second useEffect hook is not recalled when nethkinData gets updated, you should compute nethkinData into a useMemo and then add it as a dependency array of your second useEffect.

```js
const nethkinData = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    labels: backendData.map((time) => time.time),
    datasets: [
      {
        data: backendData.map((total) => 30 - total.total),
        label: "Empty parking spaces",
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(211,211,211,0.5)",
        borderColor: "rgb(211,211,211)",
      },
    ],
  };
}, [backendData]);

// ...

useEffect(() => {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("nethkinChart").getContext("2d");
  let nethkinChartStatus = Chart.getChart("nethkinChart");
  if (nethkinChartStatus != undefined) {
    nethkinChartStatus.destroy();
  }
  var nethkinChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: nethkinData,
    options: nethkinOptions,
  });
}, [nethkinData]);
```